# Unique predual of a Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $E$ is a dual Banach space whose predual is unique, and $E_0$ is a codimension 1 weak* closed subspace of $E$. Is the predual of $E_0$ necessarily unique?

Okay, I will reveal the motivation. It is a long-standing problem whether the predual of ${\rm Lip}_0(X)$, for $X$ a pointed metric space, is unique. I can prove this for ${\rm Lip}(Y)$ spaces, an important special case. If the diameter of $X$ is finite then ${\rm Lip}_0(X)$ isometrically embeds as a weak* closed codimension 1 subspace of some ${\rm Lip}(Y)$, so a positive answer to my question would resolve the finite diameter case.

I just noticed something else. In my case $E_0$ is also isometrically a quotient of $E$ by a complementary 1-dimensional subspace. Maybe that helps?

---

Editing to note that [I've posted a paper using this result on the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01812). Those 200 points were well spent!

Comment: These are preduals in the isometric sense, right?

Comment: Yes, in the isometric sense.

Comment: Is it true for $\ell_\infty$ and $L_\infty$?

Comment: I give up, is it?

Comment: I didn't check properly, but I guess it must be the image of $E_*$ in $E^*/E_0^\perp$ (which in case $E_0$ is w* closed is $E_*/E_0^\perp$).

Comment: I mean, if $F$ is a predual of $E_0$, consider its embedding in $E_0^*=E^*/E_0^\perp$. For every element of $F<E_0^*$, any extension to $E^*$ is in the image of $E_*$, isn't it?

Comment: Please clarify: By a unique predual, do you mean unique up to an (isometric) isomorphism, or do you mean unique as a subspace of $E^\ast$?

Comment: @UriBader: is it?  I don't see why.

Comment: @user95282: I mean unique up to isometric isomorphism.

Comment: @Nik Weaver: You could consider citing Uri Bader's answer here in your paper by giving the link.

Comment: @PeterMichor: I hesitated because mathoverflow pages are impermanent, but as I see in [this question](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/402/in-writing-a-research-paper-how-can-i-refer-to-peoples-answers-given-to-a-ques) it seems to be considered appropriate. I will make the change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following post is an edit of a previous one which was not accurate.
It provides a partial answer to the question.
As a compromise I decided to include also a bit of a generalization.
Thanks to Cameron Zwarich for spotting a gap in my previous post.
Thanks to Nik Weaver for suggesting a way around it using a stronger assumption and to Cameron Zwarich for identifying this assumption with the established property of having a "strongly unique predual". That was very helpful.

Recall that the Banach space $X$ is called a *unique predual* if for every isometric isomorphism $\phi:X^*\simeq Y^*$ there exists an isometric isomorphism $\phi_*:Y\simeq X$. The Banach space $X$ is called a *strongly unique predual* if moreover there exists such $\phi_*$ satisfying $\phi=(\phi_*)^*$.
The latter notion seems more natural.

Note that the existence of a Banach space which is unique predual but not strongly unique predual seems to be an open problem - at least it was in 1989 - see X.2 in "Existence and uniqueness of isometric preduals: a survey" by Godefroy (*Contemp. Math*, 131-193, **85**, 1989).
In particular, it seems that the spaces $\text{Lip}(Y)$ which motivated Nik's question are known (by him) to be strongly unique preduals, thus my answer below, though partial, does help in proving that for a bounded metric space $X$ the space $\text{Lip}_0(X)$ has a strongly unique predual.
This is mentioned as an open problem in Nik's book "Lipschitz Algebras" (p. 40).

**Theorem:** Assume $E$ has a *strongly unique predual* and $E_0<E$ is a weak*-closed subspace such that $E/E_0$ is *reflexive*.
Then also $E_0$ has a *strongly unique predual*.

The following is a compactness criterion for preduality, due to Dixmier, which I learned from the answer by Cameron Zwarich.
For a proof see also Proposition VIII.1 in the above mentioned Godefroy's survey.

**Dixmier's Compactness Criterion (DCC):** For a Banach space $X$ and a subspace $Z<X^*$, the closed unit ball of $X$ is Hausdorff compact with respect to the weak topology generated by $Z$ iff
the restriction map $X^{**}\to Z^*$ restricts to an isometric isomorphism $X\simeq Z^*$ on $X<X^{**}$.

**Lemma:** If $X$ is a strongly unique predual and $Z<X^{**}$ is a subspace such that the closed unit ball of $X^*$ is Hausdorff compact with respect to the weak topology generated by $Z$ then $Z$ coincides with the canonical image of $X$ in $X^{**}$.

*Proof of the lemma:* By DCC the map $\phi$ given by the composition $X^*\hookrightarrow X^{***}\to Z^*$ is an isometric isomorphism. Since $X$ is a strongly unique predual, we can find $\phi_*:Z\simeq X$ such that $\phi=(\phi_*)^*$. $\phi^*:Z^{**}\to X^{**}$ restricted to $Z<Z^{**}$ gives the inclusion. Its image coincides with the image of $X$, by the commutativity of the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    Z @>\phi_*>> X\\
    @V  V V @VV  V\\
    Z^{**} @>\phi^*>> X^{**}
\end{CD}

*Proof of the theorem:*
Let $E_*$ be the unique predual of $E$. Let $E_0<E$ be a weak*-closed subspace and assume $E/E_0$ is reflexive.
Let
$L=E_0^\perp<E^*$. By the weak* closedness assumption on $E_0$, upon identifying $E_*$ with its embedding in $E^*$, $L<E_*$.
We identify $L$ with $(E/E_0)^*$ and, by reflexivity, we identify $E/E_0$ with $L^*$. 
We identify $E_0$ with $(E_*/L)^*$ and argue to show that 
$E_*/L$ is a strongly unique predual of $E_0$.

Assume having an isometric isomorphism $\phi:E_0 \simeq F^*$.
Let $\phi_*$ be the isometry
$F \to F^{**} \simeq E_0^*$
and let $\pi$ be the restriction map $E^*\to E^*/L\simeq E_0^*$.
By Banach-Alaoglu the closed unit ball of $E_0$ is Hausdorff compact under the weak topology generated by $\phi_*(F)$.
It follows that the intersection of the closed unit ball of $E$ with $E_0$ is Hausdorff compact under the weak topology on $E$ generated by $\pi^{-1}(\phi_*(F))$.

We claim that also the closed unit ball of $E$ itself is Hausdorff compact under the topology generated by $\pi^{-1}(\phi_*(F))$.
To see this we establish a converging subnet for each net $x_\alpha$ in this ball. Denoting by $\bar{x}_\alpha$ its image in $E/E_0$, using the fact that $L<\pi^{-1}(\phi(F))$ generates a Haudorff compact topology on the closed unit ball of $E/E_0$ by reflexivity, we may and do pass to a subnet and assume that $\bar{x}_\alpha$ converges to $\bar{y}\in E/E_0$ for some $y\in E$.
By the Open Mapping Theorem there is a net $z_\alpha\in E_0$ with $\|(x_\alpha-y)-z_\alpha\|\to 0$. By the already established compactness of the closed unit ball in $E_0$, we may and do pass to a subnet and assume that $z_\alpha$ converges to $z\in E_0$. It follows that $x_\alpha$ converges to $y+z$.
This proves the claim.

Applying the lemma with $X=E_*$ and $Z=\pi^{-1}(\phi_*(F))<E^*$
we conclude that 
$\pi^{-1}(\phi_*(F))=E_*$ inside $E^*$.
Thus, $\phi_*(F)=\pi(\pi^{-1}(\phi_*(F)))=E_*/L$,
and by the definition of $\phi_*$ we get that $\phi=(\phi_*)^*$.

Comment: Yes, this works.  Thank you!  (BTW I think the compactness criterion should say that the unit ball of $X$ is compact Hausdorff for the weak topology, not merely compact.)

Comment: @Nik, changed to Hausdorff. Thanks!

Comment: If $\psi : \pi^{-1}(\phi(F)) \to E_*$ is an isometric isomorphism, what is the isometric isomorphism between $\phi(F)$ and $E_* / L$? I might just be missing something, but unless $\psi(L) = L$ I don't see why it exists.

Comment: @CameronZwarich: I think you're right. We actually need not just that the predual of $E$ is unique, but that it appears in $E^*$ in only one way. (Conceivably there could be two subspaces of $E^*$ which satisfy Dixmier's criterion but which are isometric to each other. Are there any examples of this?) It's okay for me because I do have this stronger condition.

Comment: @NikWeaver The established term for this stronger condition in recent literature seems to be having a strongly unique predual, and every known method of establishing a unique predual also establishes a strongly unique predual. As far as I can tell, the existence of a unique predual that is not strongly unique is still open.

Comment: Nice. Knowing the right term helps!

Comment: @Cameron, you are right, thanks. It seems that for the above argument to hold we really need the "strongly unique predual property" assumption on $E$ and accordingly it will provide a similar property for $E_0$. I understand that, luckily, this strong property does hold for the motivating examples of Nik, and in fact it is possibly equivalent to the "unique predual property". I will edit my answer accordingly in the near fututre.

Comment: Here is a survey on the subject (possibly there was some progress from 1989, though): G. Godefroy. Existence and uniqueness of isometric preduals: a survey. In: BorLuh Lin, editor, Banach Space Theory. Proc. of the Iowa Workshop on Banach Space Theory 1987, 131–193. *Contemp. Math*. **85**, 1989.

Comment: @UriBader: quoting from a reference I found by Googling *strongly unique predual*: "Clearly a strongly unique predual is a unique predual $\ldots$ This latter property is not easy to handle". It seems like *strongly unique predual* is the "right" notion.

Comment: @Nik, I believe the reference you found is the one by Godefroy I gave two comments above... Aside: I must edit my answer, as it is not correct as it is. I hesitate. I could't prove the full result you asked for in your OP so far. So if it resist proof a little longer, I will spell out what I do know. I think (though don't want to make another silly mistake) the right thing to prove is: If $E$ has a strongly unique predual and $E_0<E$ is w*-closed and co-reflexive then $E_0$ has a strongly unique predual.

Comment: Sorry, I found your reference: M-Ideals in Banach Spaces and Banach Algebras
By Peter Harmand, Dirk Werner, Wend Werner. This was my pointer to Godefroy's survey, hence my mistake.

Comment: Where do you need co-reflexivity? I just checked the argument again and didn't see any problems.

Comment: @Nik, what I meant is that we can weaken the assumption that $E/E_0$ is 1-dim to $E/E_0$ is reflexive. The proof is essentially the same. I made the edit. I hope it helps.

Comment: Very nice. Do I have your permission to include your earlier result in a paper (with credit, obviously)?

Comment: Sure! But I hesitate calling it "a new result". I suppose there are people out there who already knew it. In any case, I enjoyed thinking of it and I did learn some new things, so thank you!

Comment: What does mean $E<F$ ? It seems that it is  $E\subset F$, am I right ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Yes, I use this symbol for the inclusion of a closed subspace. I thought it is standard.

Comment: @UriBader Thanks, the discussion is really interesting.

Comment: @NikWeaver In the setting of your book, any chance that the space $\ell^\infty(\tilde{X})/\Phi(\text{Lip}_0(X))$ is reflexive? Do you have a good understanding of its Banach space properties?

Comment: I don't know, but it doesn't seem likely. $l^\infty(\tilde{X})$ is much bigger even than $\Phi(l^\infty(X))$.

Answer (score 13):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm forced to answer. I think the quotient version of this is likely to be the most fruitful. The answer there is positive for all quotients of von Neumann algebras by $\sigma$-weakly closed subspaces by a [result of Takashi Ito](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1029001949).

His proof method uses an old result of Dixmier that the preduals of $X$ correspond to the closed subspaces $Z$ of $X^*$ such that the unit ball of $X$ is compact in the weak topology induced by $Z$, with some simpler conditions to verify the compactness.

If $X$ has a unique predual and $E$ is a weak$^*$-closed subspace of $X$, then $E^\perp \subseteq X^*$ is the dual space of $X / E$ and $E^\perp \cap X_* \subseteq X^*$ is a predual of $X / E$. Suppose $E$ is a complemented one-dimensional subspace of $X$ and $Z_0 \subseteq E^\perp$ is a closed subspace that induces a weak topology making the unit ball of $X / E$ compact. Since $E$ is complemented in $X$ you should be able to extend $Z_0$ to a closed space of functionals $Z \subseteq X^*$. Since $E$ is one-dimensional, the weak topology $Z$ induces should also make the unit ball of $X$ compact. Therefore, if $X$ has a unique predual as a *subspace* of $X^*$, so does $X / E$.

Spaces with a unique predual as a subspace of the dual include von Neumann algebras and any spaces with property (X) of Godefrey-Talagrand (roughly, that there is a predual consisting of functionals that are weak$^*$ countably additive linear functionals). It seems somewhat likely that Ito's full theorem holds for spaces with property (X).

Comment: Really interesting.  Let me think about this.

Comment: Nice! The Dixmier compactness result shows in particular that the preimage in $E^*$ of the image of a predual of $E_0$ in $E^*/E_0^\perp$ is indeed a predual of $E$. This answers the question.